# SQL Query for finding the most expensive car sold in the past month

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having a problem with a query in SQL. The query I need to produce is to output details of the most expensive car sold in the past month.

My SQL code so far is below:

```
SELECT CarMake, MAX(CFSSellingPrice) AS ['PriceOfCar']
FROM CarForSale
WHERE CFSSoldDate BETWEEN CVDATE('01/02/2013') AND CVDATE('01/03/2013')
GROUP BY CarMake;
```

The problem I am getting is it is outputting more than one car, and is also not producing the most expensive car in the past month correctly.

Any help at all will be much appreciated, even if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you for your time,

Alyn :)

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: Watch out for dates being misinterpreted as month, day, year. It is generally best to put dates in the format year, month, day to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

Your query contains [`cvdate()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/type-conversion-functions-HA001229018.aspx), so I guess you are using MS Access.  If so, you can use `top 1` to find the most expensive car sold:

```
SELECT  top 1 CarMake
,       CFSSellingPrice
FROM    CarForSale
WHERE   CFSSoldDate BETWEEN CVDATE('01/02/2013') AND CVDATE('01/03/2013')
order by 
        CFSSellingPrice desc
```

Comment: Note that MS Access includes matches in Top.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Top` keyword

```
SELECT Top 1 CarMake, MAX(CFSSellingPrice) AS ['PriceOfCar']
    FROM CarForSale
    WHERE CFSSoldDate BETWEEN CVDATE('01/02/2013') AND CVDATE('01/03/2013')
    GROUP BY CarMake;
```

Comment: `top` doesn't do much without `order by`

Comment: Thank you Muhammad, this is great and works. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try the below

```
SELECT CarMake, MAX(CFSSellingPrice) AS ['PriceOfCar']
FROM CarForSale
WHERE CFSSoldDate BETWEEN CVDATE('01/02/2013') AND CVDATE('01/03/2013');
```

do not use `group by` keyword ...

Comment: Thank you for the response Mehul, but now I am getting the error of 'CarMake' as not being a part of the aggregrate function.

Comment: oh.. u got ur answer .. congo .. best luck .. :)

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you all records if for instance there are car makers who turns to have the same selling price and which was the highest price on the price range.

```
SELECT  CarMake, CFSSellingPrice
FROM    CarForSale
WHERE   CFSSellingPrice =
        (
            SELECT  TOP 1 CFSSellingPrice
            FROM    CarForSale
            WHERE   CFSSoldDate BETWEEN CVDATE('01/02/2013') AND 
                    CVDATE('01/03/2013')
            ORDER   BY CFSSellingPrice
        )
```

Comment: have you considered that there *may be* duplicate records? example, two or more car makers have sold car for 500k each (happens to be the highest selling price) and falls between your date range.

Comment: In Access `top` includes ties, no need for the subquery

Comment: @Andomar oh really? so it just like `TOP WITH TIES` in sql server?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me (using the format() to group your cars and sales and a subquery in the WHERE clause)

Has the added benefit of being able to span months.

```
SELECT 
  format(cfs.CFSSoldDate,"yyyy mm") AS SoldMonth
, cfs.CarMake
, MAX(CFSSellingPrice) AS PriceOfCar

FROM CarsForSale AS cfs

WHERE 
 cfs.CFSSoldDate BETWEEN #1/1/2013# AND #3/31/2013# 
 AND cfs.CFSSellingPrice = (SELECT 
     max(c.CFSSellingPrice) FROM CarsForSale AS c 
     WHERE format(c.CFSSoldDate, "yyyy mm") = format(cfs.CFSSoldDate, "yyyy mm"))

GROUP BY 
    format(cfs.CFSSoldDate, "yyyy mm"), cfs.CarMake
```